# How to use web fonts in ubuntu (?)

Tags: css, ubuntu, fonts, installation, webfonts

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanskr.css);

Body {
   Font-family: 'Noto Sans KR', 'Sans-serif';
}
```

I have written the code above.
Because it is a web font, can I use it without installing a font file on the server?

When developing in a local environment (Mac), no problem. In real server Ubuntu, fonts are not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why can't you use link tag as shown below?

just a suggestion.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?notosanskr">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work on a server. If your project is in simple HTML, then try running a simple python server on that folder using the terminal command:
python -m SimpleHTTPServer

And then access this from your web browser at http://localhost:8000

Troubleshooting tip: Please make sure that your computer is connected to the internet as well...

Comment: I used EC2 ubuntu server in AWS. Because it is connected from the outside, it is of course connected to the Internet. it's Nuxt App in Vue.js. Please help me Thanks.